# Correcting for multiple kruskal wallis tests

Tags: r, p-value, kruskal-wallis-test

I am running a kruskal wallis test a number of times (37) and wanted to know if I have to adjust the p-values of the kruskal tests before I look any further into the post hocs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear whether you're running one KW with 37 levels or 37 KWs (which begs several questions but here are `r` options for both...

```r
# install.packages("dunn.test")
library(dunn.test)
# using built in airquality dataset
dunn.test::dunn.test(airquality$Ozone, 
                     airquality$Month,
                     method = "holm", 
                     alpha = 0.01)
#>   Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
#> 
#> data: x and group
#> Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 29.2666, df = 4, p-value = 0
#> 
#> 
#>                            Comparison of x by group                            
#>                                     (Holm)                                     
#> Col Mean-|
#> Row Mean |          5          6          7          8
#> ---------+--------------------------------------------
#>        6 |  -0.925158
#>          |     0.5323
#>          |
#>        7 |  -4.419470  -2.244208
#>          |    0.0000*     0.0745
#>          |
#>        8 |  -4.132813  -2.038635   0.286657
#>          |    0.0002*     0.1037     0.7744
#>          |
#>        9 |  -1.321202   0.002538   3.217199   2.922827
#>          |     0.3729     0.4990     0.0052     0.0121
#> 
#> alpha = 0.01
#> Reject Ho if p <= alpha/2


set.seed(2020)
example_pvalues <-  runif(37, min = .0000000045, max = .5)
example_pvalues
#>  [1] 0.3234514211 0.1971128819 0.3092509089 0.2384455701 0.0680485967
#>  [6] 0.0336921973 0.0645763124 0.1965589675 0.0012913538 0.3101029788
#> [11] 0.3822070098 0.3719178801 0.4130828484 0.2113645443 0.2046438351
#> [16] 0.2698463088 0.4803611994 0.3267786687 0.2733576514 0.1330317863
#> [21] 0.0983978033 0.0389354644 0.4091966650 0.4712023208 0.4421122402
#> [26] 0.0829391937 0.1775506720 0.3740475097 0.2254752581 0.2779377208
#> [31] 0.4820365439 0.0357344742 0.4779045328 0.4739892955 0.0005938804
#> [36] 0.1836396416 0.0055202040
p.adjust(example_pvalues, method = "holm")
#>  [1] 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000
#>  [7] 1.00000000 1.00000000 0.04648874 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000
#> [13] 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000
#> [19] 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000
#> [25] 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000
#> [31] 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 0.02197357 1.00000000
#> [37] 0.19320714
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes its 37 KW tests each with its own multiple comparison - is there another perhaps better way of doing it as adjusting will only give me non significant results?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "will only give me non significant results"?  If you look at the help file for `p.adjust` it enumerates all the choices you have for `method` and an explanation for them.